# Azure App Service Isolated plan deployment time?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Has anyone ever experienced Azure app service (Isolated plan) taking too much time?, It's been more than two hours and it is still stuck at deploying. Does anyone know the standard time taken by isolated plans?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time looks like it does take about 1.5 hours to bring up the whole ASE on azure, tried deploying twice, time taken is same.

Hopefully, this will be faster in future.

Comment: It used to be 4h+, things are way better today.

Comment: Yes, I agree that's why I said will be faster in future like all other services that have drastically improved.

Comment: 1h15m to build the ASE yesterday, and then 35m to bring up an App Service Plan today within the isolated ASE.  Still plenty of room for improvement.